# How do I use Window.postMessage() cross domain?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, postmessage

I want to use [`Window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to get around cross-domain security issues when communicating between a parent and an iframe. How does this work?

Answer (score 4):

After bumping my head against this, I think I have an answer.

First, [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) page goes into the security issues behind cross-domain interactions. Briefly, "cross-domain" means that the URL *origins* don't match. An origin is the method, such as HTTPS, the host, such as [www.somesite.com](http://www.somesite.com), and the port number.  *The rest of the URL is ignored.* If the origins match, then same-origin rules apply; otherwise, cross-domain security kicks in.

Second, browsers consider the FILE method to be *opaque*, so the origins can't be resolved. Therefore, Window.postMessage() won't work *unless* the security is bypassed, see below.

[This MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) describes Window.postMessage(), which is designed to get around cross-domain security issues safely. The basic syntax is

```
targetwindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin)
```

*targetwindow* is the Window object to which you want to send the message. For an iframe, that's the iframe object.contentWindow. For an iframe's parent, that's window.parent.

*message* can be a string, and the documentation mentions serialization capabilities.

*targetOrigin* is the origin of the target window. The browser uses this value for security purposes, to ensure that the poster is sending the message to the destination the poster expects. The browser compares the origin of the target URL, which isn't available to the poster, to the value passed. If they don't match, an error occurs.

Note that a value of "*" may be used for *targetOrigin* to bypass security checking. Whether this is a good idea depends on the security needs of the application.

The following samples work in a cross-domain situation. I used two simple HTTP servers, one on port 8080 and the other on 8081.

Parent HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control"
        content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control"
        content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires"
        content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires"
        content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma"
        content="no-cache" />
    <title>Test Parent</title>

    <script src='./testParent.js' defer>
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>
        <button onclick='sendMessage()'>Send</button>
    </p>
    <p>
        Response:&nbsp;<span id='messageSpan'></span>
    </p>
    <iframe id='iFrame' src=''
        style='width: 20em; height: 10em;' />
</body>
```

Parent JS

```
const appOrigin = new URL(document.documentURI).origin;

const childOrigin = "http://localhost:8081";
const iFrameSrc = childOrigin + "/testChild.html" + "?parentOrigin=" + appOrigin;

const iFrame = document.getElementById("iFrame");
const messageSpan = document.getElementById("messageSpan");

// Initalize the page once it is fully loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    iFrame.src = iFrameSrc;

    window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
        if (event.origin !== childOrigin) {
            alert("Invalid message origin: " + event.origin + ", " + childOrigin);
            return;
        }

        messageSpan.innerHTML = event.data;
    });
});

const sendMessage = function () {
    iFrame.contentWindow.postMessage("Hello, child!", "*");
};
```

Child HTML

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control"
        content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control"
        content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires"
        content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires"
        content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma"
        content="no-cache" />
    <title>Test Child</title>

    <script src='./testChild.js' defer>
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>
        <button onclick='sendMessage()'>Send</button>
    </p>
    <p>
        Response:&nbsp;<span id='messageSpan'></span>
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Child JS

```
// Parent origin is passed as URL parameter
// The child should verify that the parent origin is allowed to load it
const documentParams = new URL(document.documentURI).searchParams;
const parentOrigin = documentParams.get("parentOrigin");

const messageSpan = document.getElementById("messageSpan");

// Initalize the page once it is fully loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {

    // Listen for incoming messages
    window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
        // Check the sender origin
        if (event.origin !== parentOrigin) {
            alert("Invalid message origin: " + event.origin + ", " + parentOrigin);
            return;
        }

        messageSpan.innerHTML = event.data;
    });
});

const sendMessage = function () {
    window.parent.postMessage("Hello, parent!", "*");
};
```